# Acer D-257 Netbook Need network drivers only using Flash Drive (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, connection, netbook

Is there a link where I can just download the network drivers, for me to then put it on a flash drive?

I believe its an `Acer D-257 Netbook 500GB`, running on *Windows 7 Home Premium*.

Everything works, but I have no wireless connectivity or through my Ethernet port.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: get the correct model number and we can help you, `I think` its this model number is not good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is your laptop: AOD257

1. Goto this link: [Here](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers)
2. Search your model number in the `Search by Model Number` Section
3. Locate the Network Drivers.
4. Put drivers on Flash/Thumb Drive
5. Install drivers on Acer laptop.

Comment: How do i install the drivers do i double click?Its just saving them.

Comment: thats right model.Do i need to install all drivers?Do i just click on setup on each one and it will do the rest?

Comment: You want me to explain to you how to download the files? If you can't figure that out...i don't know what to say, hire and pay a computer tech to do this for you, cause...thats basic stuff.

Download the network drivers, put them on the flash drive, install them on the ACER, when you finally get online, go back to the website and download the rest and install. Yes you have to download each one separately, there isn't 1 big file you just download and install everything at once.

Comment: It says i only need network adaptor drivers.You wouldn't know witch one that is do you?

Comment: http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/Chipset/Chipset_Intel_9.1.2.1008_W7x86_A.zip?acerid=634394029047861617&Step1=NETBOOK,%20CHROMEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE%20ONE&Step3=AOD257&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6