# Why is my Acer Webcam not working anymore?

Tags: windows-7, webcam, acer-aspire

[image]

This is what happens when I open the Acer Webcam and click the icon of it. It doesn't work for some reason. I remember yesterday I accidentally installed BlueStacks but uninstalled it afterwards.

I'm using an Acer Aspire 571 Laptop and it was working fine in the past.

Comment: relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/708061/acer-d-257-netbook-need-network-drivers-only-using-flash-drive-windows-7

Comment: what slowki said, uninstall the drivers, and download the newest drivers and see if that fixes your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to uninstall the drivers and any webcam related software, then reinstall it.